# Eml files in sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, email, moss, sharepoint-2007

I am uploading EML files to sharepoint document library.
The problem is that after uploading the file  when i click on the link of the EML file from the document library, it will be opened in html format, so i can't see the attachment,cc...

**How to solve this problem?**
I want the eml file to be opened in windows mail.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is more of a client integration issue than a SharePoint issue. What is the default association for .EML files on your system?

Check this link to associate .EML files with a particular program, e.g. Windows Mail so they open with that program:

http://email.about.com/od/outlookexpresstroubles/qt/et_eml_oe.htm

Comment: Good answer. Try from other users computers too.